# Using a Vue component to populate a Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, vuejs2

I am building an app in VueJS (3.2.29) that uses a `google.maps.Map`. I have shared a simplified version below:

```
import { h } from 'vue'
import InfoWindow from '../components/InfoWindow.js'

export default {
  template: `<div ref="mapDiv" style=" height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>`,
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {
      gMap: null,
      mapCenter: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initializeMap()
  },
  methods: {
    infowindowContent() {
      return "hello this is content"
    },
    initializeMap() {
      this.mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5, -122.6)
      this.gMap = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.mapDiv, {
        center: this.mapCenter,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      })
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.gMap,
        position: this.mapCenter,
      })
      
      const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: this.infowindowContent() })
      infowindow.open({
        anchor: marker,
        map: this.gMap,
      });
    },
},

  computed: {
    I18n: () => I18n
  }
}
```

My issue is with populating the content of the info window. It works fine with the version of `infowindowContent` defined here, which is just returning plain text. However, I want to render a Vue component called `InfoWindow` into the infowindow instead. (InfoWindow looks like this:)

```
export default {
  template: `<div>hello now it's a component</div>`,
  props: []
}
```

The google.maps.InfoWindow constructor accepts either a plain string or a DOM node for its `content` parameter; I modified `infowindowContent` to return the rendered component:

```
infowindowContent() {
  return h('InfoWindow')
}
```

The problem with this is that the call to `h()` returns a vNode instead of a DOM node. I think I need to mount this node and then return it, but I can't figure out how to mount it.

I'm also getting an error trying this:

```
let infowindow = new InfoWindow()
```

> Uncaught TypeError: InfoWindow is not a constructor

I don't understand this error - I thought this was The Way to work with Vue components.

I'm a Vue novice, so any direction is appreciated :)